# Ionic 6 not reconizing CommonsModule import for function *ngFor

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

Im working on a project running on ionic v6.
We request an array of json items from our backend & need to display this in a list. To do this we load the array in variable in our class: blablabla.page.ts.
Then in our html: blablabla.page.html we display this. We also have a blablabla.module.ts.

This page has been created with the command: ionic g page blablabla.

HTML:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>overviewMemorialPages</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
    
<ion-content>
  <div class="MemorialPageHeader">
    

    <ion-list *ngFor="let product for products">
      <ion-item>
        <h1>Hellooo!!!</h1>
        {{product.name}}
      </ion-item>
      
    </ion-list>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

page.ts

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef, Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ToastController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { RestService } from 'src/app/service/rest.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-overview-memorial-pages',
  templateUrl: './overview-memorial-pages.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./overview-memorial-pages.page.scss'],
})
export class OverviewMemorialPagesPage implements OnInit {

  products: any [] = [{
    name: "test product"
  }];

  constructor(
    private router:Router, 
    private toastController:ToastController, 
    private translate:TranslateService, 
    public restservice:RestService,
    private cd: ChangeDetectorRef,
    ) { 
    }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadPages();

    this.products.push({name: "hi"});
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.products));
  }

  showEmpty() {

  }

  loadItem(data: any) {
    console.log(data.name)
    console.log(data.description)
    console.log('view-memorial-page?id=' + data.id)
    this.cd.detectChanges();
  }

  async loadPages() {
    this.restservice.getMyMemorialPages().subscribe(
      (async (response) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response))
        // response.body.array.forEach(element => {
        //   console.log(JSON.stringify(element))
        // });

        if(response.length < 1) {
          this.showEmpty();
          return;
        }

        response.forEach((data) => this.loadItem(data))

      }),
      (async (error) => {
        console.error('ERROR: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
          let errMsg:string;

          if(error.status == 0){
            errMsg = "The service is currently unavailable. Please try again later.";
          }else{
            errMsg = error.error.error.message;
          }

          const toast = await this.toastController.create({
            message: errMsg,
            duration: 3500,
            color: 'danger',
            position: 'middle'
          });
          await toast.present();
      }),
    );
  }

}
```

All the code in here works perfectly fine, all console outputs show that it works as intented.

Module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { OverviewMemorialPagesPageRoutingModule } from './overview-memorial-pages-routing.module';

import { OverviewMemorialPagesPage } from './overview-memorial-pages.page';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    OverviewMemorialPagesPageRoutingModule,
    TranslateModule
  ],
  declarations: [OverviewMemorialPagesPage],
})
export class OverviewMemorialPagesPageModule {}
```

Here you can see we have the CommonModule imported!!

When i go and view the page i get the following error in my console:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6Iyf.png)
And no items in the list are displayed, just a blank page with only the header.

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo error!

It should be `let product of products` not `let product for products` !!!

```
<ion-list *ngFor="let product of products">
  <ion-item>
    <h1>Hellooo!!!</h1>
    {{product.name}}
  </ion-item>
  
</ion-list>
```

Comment: Omgod thank you, i would have been looking for DAYSS

Comment: it is my pleasure  @Yorick